# How to prevent DbContext from altering the database?

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, orm, code-first

I'm learning Entity Framework (currently using EF6 beta) and I'm using the code first pattern on an existing database. The entities and `DbContext` class are created automatically using a T4 template.

I would like to prevent the `DbContext` from creating / altering anything into the database at runtime.

How can I do that?

Comment: How did you create your database? EF Code First by default adds a table to the database to be able to tell whether your model has changed. If the database was not creqated by codefirst/migrations there is no data in the db and EF will not touch the schema of the databse. If you are talking about data - any time you call .SaveChanges() data in the db can be added/modified/deleted

Comment: I don't do any database structure development. I have to make my code work with it as it is. There is NO WAY I can allow it to alter objects. I tried the Database first approach but found it very limitative. I need to be able to pass random connection objects to the context and DB first didn't seemed to allow that.

Comment: CodeFirst will not change your database if it did not create it.

Comment: Well it did create new objects because I didn't mapped the schemas properly at first. I ended up having all tables recreated in the default dbo schema.

Comment: That being said, the context creating NEW objects ain't the end of the world. If really it doesn't alter anything that already exists then I might well be able to live with it. I still hate it though :)

Comment: Yes, it created new objects since it could not find any because they were not defined in the default schema. Note that since it created tables it also added the migrations history table where it keeps information about model. Therefore it was able to tell that model has changed but comparing to the tables it created and not the ones that already existed. It will also use the tables it created and not the original ones. After disabling the initializer if you change the model your model will no longer match the database and may cause runtime problems or data corruption.

Comment: You should use `.ToTable(tableName, schemaName)` to map to a table that is in non-default schema.

Comment: I figured as much afterwards. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do **enable-migrations** command, you will be presented with folder **/Migrations** under which you can find file named **Configuration.cs**. Within constructor of that file, by the default, there is a property set to value:

```
 AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
```

Which will ensure that your database won't be migrated automatically, but rather by invoking each migration manually.

However, if your database is larger than your domain models, i.e. you're just operating on the portion of already existing database, then somewhere in your application start (if it is ASP.NET app, **Application_Start** event handler), you need to add the following code:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
```

Otherwise, Entity Framework will complain that there is a mismatch between database definition in your domain model and actual current state of the database.

**EDIT:**

If you want to be sure that YourDbContext is not attempting to change database, do this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
    throw new YourCustomException("Code first changes are not allowed."); 
}
```

**EDIT again:**

I'm trying to understand what scenario are you trying to accomplish. If you have existing database, and you want to update it but only manually, this is the approach:

1. Use DbContext generator template to generate DbContext and entities
   from existing database.
2. Run enable-migrations
3. Do add-migration Initial
4. Step 3 should generate empty migration if everything was done
   properly. You can delete it.
5. Now whenever you do some change, you need to do add-migration
   ChangeName. This will not go to database, unless you do
   update-database.

Comment: If I'm throwing an exception in OnModelCreating method, then where else can I define configuration via fluent api?

Comment: Ok I'm trying to understand what you're trying to do. I've edited my post again, see if this makes sense to you now.

Comment: As I said I have a T4 template that generates entities and DbContext. I need that as I have naming and interfaces implementation requirements to follow. The default generator didn't gave me an efficient way to allow that to happen (unless I'm that much clueless on how it works). Still, I think your answer is quite complete so I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you so much for all your help. :)

Comment: I want the EF to create the Table, but I don't want it to add a migration history table. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Set the initialiser for your context to `null`.

That should leave the database in it's existing state when the application starts up.

Note that you'll get an exception if you try to run the application after altering your dbContext class and/or your database schema, as your database schema will no longer match what the context expects.

Comment: Am I right that I cannot prevent any other assembly referencing the context's assembly from changing it's initializer? I really ain't comfortable with that. :( I wished I could throw an exception on SaveChanges if the context is set in a way that database alterations are allowed. Guess it ain't meant to be used like that.

Comment: If you're concerned about the structure of the database being altered, you could just change the connection string for your context to one that doesn't give it create/alter table privileges. If you're concerned about the content of your existing tables being altered, you can use a connection string which has read only permissions for the tables you want to protect. Edit: to clarify, you'd need to set up new (restricted) accounts in your SQL server, and change your connection strings so you connect using those accounts.

Comment: To address this: "I wished I could throw an exception on SaveChanges if the context is set in a way that database alterations are allowed.", I've modified my post. Check the solution between EDIT, it might help you out.

Comment: @ThinTim I am not using a dedicated connection string for that dbcontext, it can be used with any DBConnection instance. If for some reason one user has not been granted privileges on a certain table then I prefer having the application throwing a SecurityException rather than just fetching / writing data anyway. It's an important matter I cannot just turn my back on, I'm afraid. :s

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. If you don't want your application to update any data, why not simply refrain from calling `SaveChanges()`? If you need to check whether a user has permission to make changes before calling `SaveChanges()`, why not wrap the context in a business logic layer that enforces those rules? If you need the sql server to prevent writes/alterations, why not assign a custom connection string for EF to use? If you need to hide the context from other assemblies, why not make it `internal`?

Comment: I do want the context to write in tables. I don't want it to alter them or create new ones. And I do need to be able to use the context outside it's own assembly. It's just not its job to alter the database's structure and I want to make sure it won't ever.

Comment: Also checking on permissions before each call to SaveChanges means I need to check on every changes that were made by the calling assembly so I can check on the proper tables and columns permissions on the server. No way I'm doing that to myself. :p I'm thankful for your help, but I'm afraid I'm wasting everyone's time here: EF obviously won't work the way I'd like it to.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with DBFirst and EF 6.1 it was creating a new table based on the EntityName. So I modified the OnModelCreating virtual method to map my tables.

So if the EntityName was named MyStuffs since by default the EnitityNames are pluralized which you do have the option to deselect that during the EF generation. In my case the wizard was generating the pluralized version of the table.

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=MyEntityConnectionName")
    {
    }
    public MyContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
    #region methods

    public static MyContext Create()
    {
        return new MyContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        // Map Entities to their tables.
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>().ToTable("MyStuff"); //prevent a new table from being added since we added a mapping
    }

    #endregion
    public virtual DbSet<MyModel> MyEntities{ get; set; }
}
```