# Should user codefirst entityframework for database large (> 60 table)

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, code-first

I'm doing project have  60 table in data base, I should use codefirst or datafirst entityframe work

Comment: It doesn't matter. However you're less likely to make mistakes if you make the database first, especially when you have to create many databases (probably with relations between them?)

Comment: You already have the DB in place and now you are starting your coding. This implies that your logic lies in the DB so you should go with DB first.

Comment: To add more on this:

There are no set rule's which govern/favor db first or code first approach. The difference between the two is, using db first you create your model using EF, were as using code first you define your own model.

Comment: Please use Twitter for these kinds of announcements. This is not a question *at all*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the number of tables it would really depend on those required for your domain model.  Is all 60 of them required for modelling your domain problem?

You may want to think about [bounded contexts](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) to split your domain model down into specific areas of your application.  A large graph of entities can get messy.

It can be achieved either way using code first and [preventing the database from being materialised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863512/how-to-prevent-dbcontext-from-altering-the-database) from your Fluent API mappings or modelling your domain model from a database in an EDMX file.