# Replacing DbContext in Microsoft MVC Individual User Accounts Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I just created my first MVC Website.
To avoid having to program the controller myself, I am using the *Individual User Accounts* template from Microsoft.

I know, that this template uses the Entity Framework to create an express database to persist the user/account data.

Since I already have a database, which I want to use, I want to change the 
template so it uses the DbContext for said database.

I was able to change the connectionString, so that the tables of the template got created in my database. But I don't want it to create it's own tables but use my already created tables.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Or should I just write the whole account/user controller from scratch myself?

Comment: try the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863512/how-to-prevent-dbcontext-from-altering-the-database

Comment: `But I don't want it to create it's own tables but use my already created tables`   see my answer below   `Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);`

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is an example of DbContext class  it implements DbContext
// If you do not use constructor(s) then the expectation by entity framework
// will be that your name of your connectionstring in web.config 
// or app.config is name name as your class  so e.g.  "YourContext",                        
// otherwise   "Name="YourConnectionString"
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    // constructor as you wish /want 
    public YourContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        { }  

    // critical mapping 
    public DbSet<someModel> someModel { get; set; }

    // critical overide 
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // critical key to NOT let your database get dropped or created etc...
        Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);

        // This is an example of mapping model to table 
        // and also showing use of a schema ( dbo  or another )
        modelBuilder.Entity<someModel>().ToTable("someTable", schemaName: "dbo");

    }
}
```