# How to use a different connection string (but same database) for migrations

Tags: entity-framework

I have been using a connection string like this to connect my website to my database:

```
<add name="MyDb" 
     connectionString="Data Source=MyDb;
     Initial Catalog=Staging;
     User Id=website_staging;
     Password=secret;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The `website_staging` user is a member of the `db_ddladmin` role so that when I publish, and my `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initialiser runs, it has the permissions required to migrate the database to the latest version automatically.

I want to reduce the standard user's permissions (by adding it only to the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles) and connect with a different user (in the `db_ddladmin` role) during migrations.

So I added another connection string with a different name and user:

```
<add name="Migrations" 
     connectionString="Data Source=MyDb;
     Initial Catalog=Staging;
     User Id=website_staging_migrations;
     Password=secret;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And I changed the name of the connection string used by the context initialised in my `DatabaseMigrationConfig` class:

```
public class DatabaseMigrationConfig
{
    internal static void Register()
    {
        using (var context = new MyDbContext(Name="Migrations"))
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, 
                                    Migrations.Configuration>());
            context.Database.Initialize(false);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the constructor of my `Migrations.Configuration` class I also changed the connection string:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SID2013Context>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Migrations"].ConnectionString;
        TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(cs, "System.Data.SqlClient");
    }
}
```

I then tried publishing the website. It appears to correctly pick the connection string with the higher rights, but it attempts to run the `Initial` migration. How can I stop it doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved this by adding the `website_staging_migrations` user to the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles as well as the `db_ddladmin` role.

The user obviously needs to read the data in the `__MigrationHistory` table. What threw me was that EF doesn't report the failure to access the table as an error and instead I got this error when it tried to run the initial migration:

```
There is already an object named '----' in the database.
```

And the user also needs to write to the `__MigrationHistory` table. I got this error until I added the user to the `db_datawriter` role:

```
The INSERT permission was denied on the object '__MigrationHistory',
database 'Staging', schema 'dbo'.
```

Comment: Makes sense. Because of security principles, you shouldn't be able to tell the difference between "this table doesn't exist" and "you don't have rights to this table".  And "this table doesn't exist" equates to "initial migration not done"