# How to set Entity Framework Core migration timeout?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using the latest (1.0.0) version of EF Core. I have a migration to run on a quite big database.

I run:

> dotnet ef database update -c ApplicationDbContext

And get:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

In the connection string I explicitly set the timeout like so:

> Connect Timeout=150000

Unfortunately, it didn't help. How should I do this?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The error message you are getting is for a **Command** timeout, not a connection timeout.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by [Pace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202694/pace) in comments, since EF Core 2.0 you are able to use `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` to change the behaviour of your context when it is being created by tooling at design time such as happens with Migrations.

Create a separate class in your project that implements the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` interface and use the `DbContextoptionsBuilder` to configure the behaviour you want - in this case, setting the command timeout value to 600 seconds:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace EFCoreSample.Model
{
    public class SampleContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<SampleContext>
    {
        public SampleContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SampleContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;",
                opts => opts.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds));

            return new SampleContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that your existing `DbContext` has a constructor that takes a `DbContextOptions` object as a parameter:

```
public AdventureContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options){}
```

When the tooling runs the migration, it looks first for a class that implements `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` and if found, will use that for configuring the context. Runtime behaviour is not affected.

**Original Answer No Longer Applies**

<strike>There is no way to set the `CommandTimeout` on a context when using EF commands. But you can set it globally in the constructor, and then remove it later if you don't need to keep it:</strike>

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetCommandTimeout(150000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Created issue asking about allowing for timeouts specific to migrations: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6613

Comment: note that these are seconds, so the timeout set here is about two days.

Comment: @BobbyTables Yes - the actual number comes from the question, but your point is a valid one.

Comment: As a workaround, is there any condition I can use to increase the timeout only for migrations? Like `if (IsMigrations()) { Database.SetCommandTimeout(1500) }`

Comment: @Igor Not that I know of but I haven't been keeping up with EF Core recently.

Comment: @Igor If you are using EF Core (>2.0) and you want the timeout to apply for CLI migration (e.g. `dotnet ef database update`) then you can control how the context object is created in `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` or `Program.BuildWebHost` (see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/1x-2x-upgrade)).  If you are doing it programmatically then you are creating a context object yourself.  Just add a constructor argument (with a default) to your context.

Comment: For assigning timeout values, I prefer to use `TimeSpan` so the intent is clear: `(int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20).TotalSeconds`

Comment: Is this still the case that it is global? I often want a long timeout for maintenance type jobs but not for normal CRUD stuff. This is quite bizarre. This DI stuff can really bite you sometimes.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver As Pace mentioned in his comment, there is a solution now. I've updated the answer to provide an example.

Comment: it'd be great to inject the connection string though.

Comment: "$ dotnet ef" will use your host builder to configure your context, if you have one.

Comment: @François, I improved Mike Brind's answer by reading the connection string from the appsettings file. See my answer below.

Answer (score 40):

You can set the timeout for migration only by setting the timeout on the context before calling the Migrations method:

```
using (var context = new DispatchingDbContext(_configuration))
{
    context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(300);
    await context.Database.MigrateAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

[Set timeout for migrations ef .netcore](https://pgroene.wordpress.com/2017/12/05/set-custom-timeout-for-code-first-migrations-entity-framework-core-2-0)

Comment: where do you put this?

Answer (score 10):

You can do it also in the constructor of your database context class.

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
    Database.SetCommandTimeout(150000);
}
```

Comment: This works but it applies to everything, not just the migration. Seems like there should be a way to apply it to only the migration.

Comment: thanks, this helped, it is just you set it as a property not a function: Database.CommandTimeout = 150000;

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the migration SQL script and run it on your own directly on the SQL server using this command:

```
dotnet ef migrations script [Baseline migration]
```

This way you won't be limited to timeout limitations.

More info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#sql-scripts).

To generate this [script for Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#getting-a-sql-script), use:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: [Baseline migration]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Entity Framework 6 (NOT CORE!), I set a longer timeout for migrations using the `DbMigrationsConfiguration.CommandTimeout` property.

Like this:

In my Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    DatabaseMigrationConfig.Register();
    //etc
}
```

My `DatabaseMigrationConfig` Class:

```
public class DatabaseMigrationConfig
{
    internal static void Register()
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext(Config.ConnectionStringMigrations))
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext,
                                        Migrations.Configuration>());
            context.Database.Initialize(false);
        }
    }
}
```

My `Migrations.Configuration` class:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        CommandTimeout = 360;// <----- 6 minute timeout!
    }
}
```

References:

[Migrations: timeout error in Update-Database commands](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/827)
[DbMigrationsConfiguration.CommandTimeout Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.commandtimeout)

Note that I also use a different connection string during migrations - the user has higher permissions than the website and the connection timeout is longer. See this question - [How to use a different connection string (but same database) for migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342172/how-to-use-a-different-connection-string-but-same-database-for-migrations)

Comment: Are you sure, your answer is valid for Entity Framework **CORE**?

Comment: I am not sure, because I'm not using it, but I would have thought that it would be easy to check if I had downloaded it and was using it already. Are you saying that the `DbMigrationsConfiguration.CommandTimeout` has been removed from Core?

Comment: There is no DbMigrationsConfiguration in EF Core. It has been removed.

Comment: The answer is good, but please specify that it's for "Entity Framework 6  **(not Core)**" as people get confused :)

Comment: I was looking for an answer for non CORE EF6 and this was the only answer I could find. Please ensure this answer stays upvoted as whilst it isn't for the question asked it was very helpful.

Comment: This answer should be somewhere else. This is confusing. Please remove it and place it on the corresponding question

Comment: @Julian very happy to. Can you provide a link to the corresponding question?

Comment: @Colin I guess this one. But haven't checked if your answer is a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051417/code-first-custom-sql-migration-timeout-exception

Answer (score 0):

I improved [Mike Brind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39012033/1122629) by reading the connection string from the appsettings file:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace EFCoreSample.Model
{
    public class SampleContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<SampleContext>
    {
        public SampleContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT");
            var settingsFileName = $"appsettings.{env}.json";
            
            if (!File.Exists(settingsFileName))
            {
                settingsFileName = "appsettings.json";
            }
            
            var connectionString = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(settingsFileName).Build().GetConnectionString("GlobalConnection");

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SampleContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                opts => opts.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds));

            return new SampleContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Small modification to [Patrick Koorevaar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70987916) to account for layered appsettings.json files...

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        
        var settingsFileName = "appsettings.json";
        if (File.Exists(settingsFileName))
        {
            builder.AddJsonFile(settingsFileName);
        }
        
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT");
        var envSettingsFileName = $"appsettings.{env}.json";
        if (File.Exists(envSettingsFileName))
        {
            builder.AddJsonFile(envSettingsFileName);
        }
        
        var connectionString = builder.Build().GetConnectionString("MyConnString");

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
            opts => opts.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds));

        return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From EF Core 7 you now don't need to use the `DesignTimeFactory` to determine if it is the migrations running vs the application. The `DesignTimeFactory` is a pain because of all the Configuration setup.

Now you can do the following in your context:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IConfiguration config) : base(options)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (EF.IsDesignTime)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), opt => opt.CommandTimeout(600));
        }
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
```

Replace "DefaultConnection" with the connection string's key from your appsettings file.