# how to solve timeout issue occured while updating the entries in database

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2016-express

A timeout error occurred while registering the record or updating the records in the database.

> *"The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."*

Application throw   DbUpdateException error on running the update API.

Error  below -

> - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
> - System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of CommandTimeout is 30s. You can modify it according to your needs.

In your `Program.cs` file (**.Net 6**),

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
    options =>options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, op => 
        op.CommandTimeout(60)));
```

Or [you can set it through your context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45994516/7687666).

**Related Post:**

[What is the difference between SqlCommand.CommandTimeout and SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847275/7687666)